Basic questions about grothendieck ring $K(X)$
Let $X$ be a connected regular noetherian scheme with an ample sheaf, so that $K(X)=K^\cdot(X)=K_\cdot(X)$. I want to ask whether each class of a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ is nonzero in $K(X)$. For locally free sheaves, I believe the set of isomorphism classes of locally free sheaves injects into $K(X)$, as I recall solving an exercise in Hartshorne some time ago, which shows that $\text{rank}: K(X)\to \mathbb{Z}$ is well defined.
I want to then conclude that $[\mathcal{F}][\mathcal{G}]$ is nonzero if $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G}$ is nonzero. In particular, I hope that if $\mathcal{G}$ is locally free then the product in $K(X)$ would be nonzero. More generally, I want to ask to what extent a class of locally free sheaf is non-zero-divisor. What I can be sure are only the classes of line bundles, as they are units.
For background, I am reading Yu. I. Manin's book (or note?) about K-functors and so far the only calculation I have seen is that of projectivized bundles $\mathbb{P}_X(\mathcal{E})$ (which was surprisingly hard).

In general it is not true that the class of a nonzero sheaf is nonzero. For instance, consider $X = \mathbb{A}^1$ and let $F$ be the structure sheaf of the point $0 \in \mathbb{A}^1$. Then it has a free resolution
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X \to F \to 0,
$$
where the first map is the multiplication by the coordinate. Therefore,
$$
[F] = [\mathcal{O}_X] - [\mathcal{O}_X] = 0.
$$
On the other hand, if $X$ is smooth and projective, the class of a nonzero sheaf is indeed nonzero.
Edit. Indeed, the Hilbert polynomial of a nonzero sheaf $F$ is nonzero, and as it is additive in exact sequences, it defines a map $K_0(X) \to \mathbb{Q}[t]$.

Thank you for the nice example! I see that kind of simple resolution for the structure sheaf of a divisor cannot occur if $X$ is smooth projective, as we have degree on Picard group. But it is still far from proving your last sentence, so could you please give a sketch of proof? (Or a reference if it is too long)

OK, I added a brief explanation.
